# Directories showing as files when browsing a Time Machine backup on Windows

Tags: time-machine, windows, hfs+

I have to grab some files from a time machine backup and I only have a Windows PC.  I downloaded the HFS+ filesystem drivers from MacRoumers (here) and plugged in my Time Machine Drive.  Everything appears normal, until I transverse into a specific backup.  There I see the "Library" directory, and every other folder (Desktop, Movies, Music...) are files.  It's like this in every backup instance, and I'm stuck.  I don't recall these folders being symlinks to earlier backups, but I could be wrong and these drivers don't support symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

When Time Machine makes a backup it only copies changed files and creates links to the older items. AFAIK these are not symlinks, but hardlinks.

Sample output from Time Machine
`23/06/2014 10:40:19.087 pm com.apple.backupd[12797]: Copied 4 items (33 bytes) from volume DeepThought. Linked 20.`

Comment: You can't hardlink a directory, even so these links must point somewhere on the drive - where are the original files?

Comment: If they are symlinks (and not some proprietary Apple format) then you can simply look at the contents in a text viewer which will show the target of the link.

Comment: None of them have any content.  They're all 0 bytes.

Comment: They probably have content in the Resource fork like an Alias. Either way I think you are out of luck trying to access on a Windows system. Even the BSD Unix commands on a Mac have no knowledge of some Apple constructs.